# Как получить данные из бд в <Select><option></option></Select> c условием

Tags: html, sql, база-данных, django

Как можно делать выпадающий список так, чтобы данные взялись из бд с условием.
у меня есть две таблицы questions и options_selections, нужно для каждого вопроса из questions создать выпадающий список из options_selection. Содержание 
выпадающего списка с помощью SQL наверное выглядел бы так

```
 SELECT option_name  FROM options_selection o, question q
    WHERE o.question_id = q.id;
```

Но я не понятно как это можно отобразить в html.
У меня для каждого вопроса в выпадающем списке выводит все option_name из options_questions. Буду очень благодарен за любой совет!

Вот модели, контроллер и html файл c с которыми я работаю

Модели

```
     class questions(models.Model):  
            question_name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)           
            class Meta:
                verbose_name = 'Вопросы'
                db_table = 'questions'

    class options_selection(models.Model):  
        question = models.ForeignKey(questions, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        option_id = models.IntegerField()
        option_name = models.TextField()
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'options_selection'
            unique_together = (('question', 'option_id'),)
 Views 

    from myproj.models import questions, options_selection

    def addprofile(request):
        quest = questions.objects.all()
        option = options_selection.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'dappx/add_anketa.html', {"quest": quest, 'option': option})
```

add_anketa.html

```
{% for qu in quest %}
   <ul> {{qu.question_name }} </ul>      
    <select>
        {% for o in option %}
            <!--o = o.filter(question = qu.id) -->
            <option value={{ qu.id }}>{{ o.option_name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}    
    </select>

 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем, кто пытался решить задачу. Нашел способ как это делать.

В add_anketa.html внутри select необходимо было ставить проверку, а не только option

```
 {% if o.question.id == qu.id %}
      <option value={{ qu.id }}>{{ o.option_name }}</option>
 {% endif %}
```